# service fabric auto-balancing on CPU

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to ascertain if Service Fabric will automatically balance a cluster based on the CPU load on one of its nodes.

According to the MSDN literature, Service Fabric automatically balances on **metrics** (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-balancing/). The default metrics are Count and Primary Count and we can define and report other metrics. But, there is no mention of moving replicas and balancing the cluster if a node becomes too "hot" (i.e. high CPU).

I set up the following to try and simulate this scenario.

I created A Service Fabric application that I deployed to 5 node Azure cluster with the following services:

1. Stateful service with a simple int count. It exposes a remoting interface that increments the count and also keeps the CPU busy for 1 second. This service is partitioned into 10 named partitions - a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j.
2. A Web API stateless service that calls the above interface for a requested partition.
3. A stateless services that monitors the node CPU and reports a health warning if the CPU exceed 50%

Once the application is deployed to the cluster, I note two partitions that have the same primary node. For example, partitions "a" and "c" both have their primary on "node 1". Then I run locally a client app locally that calls the above web API every second for these two partitions. As expected, the CPU on "node 1" goes to around 90% for the duration of the test, but even after running the test for 5 minutes, the replicas are not moved around to balance the node. in fact, in some cases, the client calls start timing out.

Does the above experiment prove that Service Fabric does not auto-balance on CPU load or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, health warnings are not doing anything for the balancing of the cluster. The only thing that triggers the balancing are load reports.

It is however true it does **not** balance on CPU. You need to specify your own resources to balance upon in the cluster/applicationmanifests. Then you can dynamically report load in your application, however this are virtual resources as per the answer I got on my question last week. [Resource usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112687/how-to-measure-resource-usage-on-partitionlevel-in-service-fabric)

Comment: I used health warnings simply to visually report back when the CPU exceeded a certain load - it wasn't intended as a flag for balancing. The reference to your question does point me in the right direction, though.  Thanks!

Comment: It worth trying an empirical way of LB. Probably your cluster has an API what you can ping. Try to put the more load on nodes with the fastest response. CPU and other resources might reflect the actual load but it is better to test the responsiveness.